# 403 Forbidden after a POST request - PHP, Slim

Tags: php, apache, slim

I've build a small CMS and from the admin panel - after sending the form using POST method with all the fields that will be stored in the database, I receive 403 Forbidden instead of redirect to the url that will show me same fields with the latest values (the same form that I can send again using POST).

I do not have access to the server and I cannot use phpinfo() for e.g. What do I need to check in order to find why this happens?

Comment: with 403 errors I would start looking at apache or nginx logs. But you say you don't have access to them which is well obviously challenging. `phpinfo()` won't tell you much at all. How do you deploy files? I'm wondering whether the new index page has incorrect access permissions (chmod)

Comment: Use a server you can access and check its settings

Comment: The deploying of files is done through git hooks and I have access only to development branch. I doubt it is because of incorrect permissions of the index file, because I never write there. When I've worked locally this problem didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are simply not logged in ;)